# Magento 2 change productname adding to cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I need to change the productname visible for the customer after adding it to the cart. Also it should show on invoice, order email and everything else visible for the customer.

I made an extension with observer checkout_cart_product_add_after

```
   $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');            
   $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
   $item->getProduct()->setName('this is the productname');
   $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

But the original productname is still visible on minicart, cartpage, etc.

The 'add to cart message' is the only place where the new changed productname is visible. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solutions myself.

Hope this helps anyone searching for it, or if you have comments how it could be done a better way, please let me know.

Created a plugin with this code:

```
class Item 
{
    public function afterSetProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
        $result
    ){
        $subject->setName('New Name');
    }
}
```

So this sets a new name to the quote item, visible in everything, excepting cart and mini cart.

Now I have got my new productname visible in:

- Added to cart message
- Quote-item, even in admin and invoices

But not in:

- Mini cart
- Cartpage

For the cart page:

I changed output of function getProduct in Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer:

```
class Renderer
{
    public function afterGetProductName(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject,
        $result
    ){
        return 'this is the name';
    }
}
```

For minicart, also with plugin:

```
class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData(
     \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ){
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $data['product_name'] = 'this is the productname';
        return $data;    
}
```