# Magento 2 : Update the product name while adding into the cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, quote, quoteitem

I want to add something with the product name dynamically while adding to the cart. Each product have different concatenation with product name. And that product name should be updated on everywhere like cart page, checkout, email, invoice, in sales grid etc.
I have followed the step from below link. But product name has been updated in whole quote items not only the last added item.
[Magento 2 change productname adding to cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315254/magento-2-change-productname-adding-to-cart)

```
namespace vendor\modulename\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote;


class Item 

{
   public function afterSetProduct(
     \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
      $result
   ){

      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
    $product_name = $cookieManager->getCookie('proname');
    $product_Id = $cookieManager->getCookie('proid');
    $productId =  $subject->getProductId();
    if($productId == $product_Id){
     $subject->setName($product_name);
     return $subject;
    }
}
```

}

For mini-cart

```
namespace vendor\modulename\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;

 class DefaultItem    
 {

    public function aroundGetItemData(
     \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ){
        
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
        $product_name = $cookieManager->getCookie('proname');
        $pro_id = $cookieManager->getCookie('proid');
        $logger->info('text message11212 default');
        $data = $proceed($item);
        if($proceed($item)['product_id'] == $pro_id){       
         $data['product_name'] = $product_name;
        }else{
            $data['product_name'] = $data['product_name'];
        }       
        return $data;    
    }
}
```

For cart page

```
namespace vendor\modulename\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item;

class Renderer

{

    public function afterGetProductName(

         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject,
        $result
    ){

        $ $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
        $product_name = $cookieManager->getCookie('proname');
        $pro_id = $cookieManager->getCookie('proid');       
        return $product_name;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you try that solution provided into that URL?

Comment: yes, I have tried but it's updated all the product name with the name not the updated the only last item

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: Dhiren I have updated the code please check

Comment: Have you debug that you will get productId data properly on this one?

Comment: yes, i have checked that in aroundGetItemData and getting correct data in array

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?